# How to setup keyword detection matching for intents in Lex?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

I want my bot to match the intent Help whenever user types /help followed by anything. eg `/help i am unable to switch on laptop`.
Here, the latter part can be anything, of any length.
I have given two slots - `keyword and query`.
In keyword slot I have given '/help' and for query slot I gave many random examples but even then when i test it for something new, it fails to match any intent.
Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: also, we cannot give / in the utterances so we must define it in some slot. utterance can consist only of Unicode characters, spaces, periods for abbreviations, underscores, apostrophes, and hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

Lex is a conversational engine and - in my experience - ignores all punctuation as it is not able to be spoken.

You may have to replace `/help` with a phrase like `help me with ...`, `how can I ...`.

If you are using your own front end (as opposed to FB integration) you can consider adding an intermediary that will catch `/help` messages and forward the remaining on to a Lex bot that specifically handles help requests.

Comment: Lex has many limitations, like the one you mentioned and no fall-bback intent. to overcome those i have added intermediary lambda function.